# Accessing array elements by index on a remote machine via ssh

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, ssh

On a remote machine, I need to get the values ​​of 2 arrays at the same time. That is, 1 element of 1 and 2 arrays, then 2 element of 1 and 2 arrays, and so on.

When writing a script, I ran into a problem that when I specify the array index using a variable, only the first element of the array is displayed and that's it. I tried escaping and writing like this [$i] but no result. What am I doing wrong? And what is the right way to access array elements by index?

What i want to get:

```
array1=("1" "2")
array2=("a" "b")

ssh $user_srv@$ip_srv -p $port_srv 'bash -s' << EOF
for i in "${!array1[@]}"
do
    echo '${array1[$i]}'
    echo '${array2[$i]}'
done
EOF
```

Result:

```
1
a
2
b
```

Comment: Quotes don't have their normal escaping properties inside a heredoc - did you try escaping with `\$i`?

Comment: But even that by itself isn't sufficient here - the arrays don't exist on the remote machine so you can't loop over their values.

Comment: In the way you wrote your here-doc, parameter expansion happens before `ssh` is invoked. At this time, the variable `i` is still undefined.

Comment: @tjm3772 Unfortunately that doesn't work. `syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$i")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the code you want to run as a *local* function; then use `declare -f` to serialize that function, and `declare -p` to serialize the data it uses, to pass them over the wire.

```
array1=("1" "2")
array2=("a" "b")

rmt_func() {
  for i in "${!array1[@]}"; do
    echo "${array1[$i]}"
    echo "${array2[$i]}"
  done
}

ssh "$user_srv@$ip_srv" -p "$port_srv" 'bash -s' <<EOF
  $(declare -p array1 array2)
  $(declare -f rmt_func)
  rmt_func
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the arrays don't exist on the remote machine, this code solves the problem by looping through the arrays on the local machine and generating `printf` commands to send to the remote machine to print the elements:

```
array1=("1" "2")
array2=("a" "b")

for i in "${!array1[@]}"; do
    printf 'printf "%%s\\\\n" %q\n' "${array1[i]}"
    printf 'printf "%%s\\\\n" %q\n' "${array2[i]}"
done | ssh "$user_srv@$ip_srv" -p "$port_srv" 'bash -s'
```

- The `%q` format with `printf` causes the corresponding argument (in this case an array element) to be output in a format that can be reused as shell input.  That ensures that the code works for array elements that contain whitespace or shell metacharacters.
- `echo` is not safe for printing arbitrary string values so I used `printf` instead.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).